# Generating list with n values of "x" and p of "y"

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a list in r with two unique components, "x' and "y". In this list I need n of "x" and p of "y".

For example; I want three "dog" and two "cat" so that my list looks like

```
list = c("dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat")
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: I agree with moooh's answer. If you decide you need a list after all, you can do as.list(animals) after following his idea. In addition, it is wise to not use the pre-existing R function name "list" as a variable name. That might cause troubles later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R lists and vectors are different things. I think you need a vector. To accoplish what you want you can use the `rep()` function like so:

```
n <- 5
p <- 2
animals <- c(rep("dog",n),rep("cat",p))
```

Comment: You could do `rep(c("dog", "cat"), c(3, 2))` to avoid calling `rep` twice.